# Why bindings do not work?

Tags: zk

```
<textbox  id="nextTitleTextbox" readonly="true" value="@bind(ivm.inventory.successorTitleName)" />
<button   id="nextTitleButton" label="..." mold="trendy" onClick="@command('chooseFormerOrSuccessor', isFormer = false)"/>
<a        id="nextTitleHrefView" href="/inventory_new.do?method=edit&amp;docUID=${ivm.inventory.successorTitleName}">view</a>
<a        id="nextTitleHrefHistory" href="javascript:showRenamingHistory(${ivm.inventory.successorTitleName},${ivm.inventory.successorTitleName})">history</a>
```

The problem is in 'a' tags. Textbox and buttons works fine, but links in 'a' tags do not catch information from binding, so link there looks like `/inventory_new.do?method=edit&amp;docUID=`. I really don't understand what's wrong here, because I tried a lot of combination and something similar is working on other pages. Where is mistake in this binding?

I even tried to put string from zscript

```
<zscript>
        String successorTitleHref = "/inventory_new.do?method=edit&amp;docUID=" + ivm.inventory.successorTitleName;
</zscript>
```

But got exception:

```
Typed variable declaration : Class or variable not found: ivm.inventory.replacementTitleName.
```

Also, it's supported controls, that locates in separate file, and every control adding with use derective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding in ZK has nothing to do with variable replacement. `@bind()` doesn't mean you can use `${...}`. The two are completely separate concepts even though both are called "EL Expression" in the manual. But [binding EL Expression](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/EL%20Expression) and [ZUML EL Expressions](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Composing/ZUML/EL%20Expressions) are two different things.

To allow access to `ivm` in a `zscript`, you need to define this variable somewhere in the script. One way is to instantiate it:

```
IVM ivm = new IVM();
```

or you can use a [custom variable resolver](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Composing/ZUML/EL%20Expressions#Variable_Resolver).